# Tomcat & Solr - do i need to regenerate solr.war if solrconfig.xml or other conf files being modified?

Tags: tomcat, solr

Once i deploy solr.war to tomcat under webapps folder, if i wanna test some changes in solrconfig.xml, do i need to everytime generate a new solr.war and redeploy? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to redeploy or restart tomcat.  You do not need generate a new solr.war.  Solr configuration is outside solr.war as identified by solr.home variable.

However if you are using solr with multiple cores, you can do a RELOAD of the core to pickup configuration changes. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) I meant to modify solrconfig.xml which is located under solr/corexxx/conf, paralel to where schema.xml is. Hmm..let me rephrase my question. If i have my own solr.war and i add it to Tomcat's webapp directory; once i start tomcat, solr.war will be unpacked to webapp/solr directory. Now if i make changes to web/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml, will this be applied? or maybe solr.war will be unpacked again and my changes will get overwritten?

Comment: In your web.xml you must have set solr/home as env-entry as outlined in this (ignore for a sec that it is a resin doc). http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrResin. This points to a solr.home folder -the one containing relevant solrconfig.XML .  This solr/home setting externalizes your solr configuration from the war file and this is how production deployments refer configuration for solr.